# How to make all "unique" pairs from list in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Say we have list [1,2,3].
How to make "unique" pairs [1,2], [1,3], [2,3] in tensorflow?

Comment: Is the size of the list fixed (known at graph construction time) or can it change on each session run? And can the list have duplicate elements, and in that case should that be taken into account to avoid repeated pairs?

Comment: Unfortunately size of list is conditional(not fixed). No duplicates in list.

Answer (score 0):

You need [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in python.

```
from itertools import combinations
L = [1, 2, 3]
Q=[",".join(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(L, 2)]
print(Q)
```

Comment: Thank you. There is no problem to implement required functionality In imperative languages. I need that in tensorflow(symbolic, vector operations).